# Restrict access to included files

Tags: .htaccess

I have an `inc` folder for all the php functions, classes, js, css and more. I've made an .htaccess file with `Deny from all` in it in the directory `inc`. All my .php files get included properly on index.php, but I can't call any CSS. How to fix .htaccess in order to allow access to the specified subfolders (inc/css and inc/js) and still block the execution of everything else in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use **[FilesMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#filesmatch)** in your `.htaccess` file to apply a specific set of rules only if the requested resource is of a certain type (extension).

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|inc)$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to fix .htaccess in order to allow access to the specified subfolders (inc/css and inc/js) and still block the execution of everything else in it?

You can either put htaccess files in the `inc/css` and `inc/js` directories that just has:

```
Options -Indexes
Allow from all
```

Or you can change the htaccess file that you have in the `inc` directory to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^css/? - [L]
RewriteRule ^js/? - [L]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,F]
```